# Eloquent many-to-many returning an empty value

Tags: php, laravel, database, join, eloquent

Good day. I am trying to convert some of my models to use Eloquent mechanisms from table joins. I have three tables, and I want to use one of them as a pivot table. The three tables are shown below
First table (cp_cases_counsel)
[image: cp_cases_counsel]

Followed by (cp_counsel)
[image: cp_counsel]

Then,(cases_sc)
[image: cases_sc]

I am trying to implement a many-to-many relationship between cases_sc and cp_counsel using cp_cases_counsel as the pivot table.

These are my models

```
use App\Models\SupremeCases;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\CounselCase;

class Counsel extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [];
    protected $table = 'cp_counsel';
    protected $connection = 'mysql2';


    public function supreme()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(SupremeCases::class,'cp_cases_counsel','counsel_id','suitno');
    }

}
```

For the Cases Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Counsel;

class SupremeCases extends Model
{
    //
    protected $connection = "mysql2";
    protected $fillable = [];
    protected $table = 'cases_sc';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function counsels()
    {
        
        return $this->belongsToMany(Counsel::class,'cp_cases_counsel','counsel_id','suitno');
    }
}
```

Getting the counsels and their cases using
`$counsels = Counsel::with('supreme')->get();`

I get an empty result for the supreme node in the response as shown below
[image]

Please, what I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: You have the same key order for both models. Try switching `counsel_id` and `suitno` on your Counsel model

Comment: I did, and still got the same response

Comment: Try switching the `counsel_id` and `suitno` on your SupremeCases model